# How to make value of HorizontalGauge be continuously updated in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I wrote the following code:

```
Manipulate[HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, range}], {range, 5, 10}]
```

I want to plot a `HorizontalGauge` with dynamic range, but the marker of the `HorizontalGauge` does not respond to dragging, I could only click on the axis to change value of x, how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: `TrackedSymbols :> {range}` will fix the problem with dragging it, but it is unlikely to work for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, it works if it's wrapped with Manipulate[], but what if there is no Manipulate, just HorizontalGauge[], and "range" is a value varying with another function, i wrote "Dynamic[range]", but it didn't work.

Comment: i add a picture to explain what i meant, if i change the value of "range" by the Slider[], the HorizontalGauge dosn't work when i drag it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dynamic[HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, range}], TrackedSymbols :> {range}]

Slider[Dynamic[range], {5, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, TrackedSymbols is one of my problems, i found out another, i put the calculation of "range" in the Graphics[] which controlled by Dynamic[x], now it's solved.